# Is it possible to have multiple redis servers with 1 celery app

Tags: celery

We use celery heavily and redis is getting overloaded at times as we increase the number nodes running celery worker. Is it possible to have celery workers configured to read from different redis instances based on the queue name.

I found questions for supporting same redis across multiple celery apps but not the same app with multiple redis.

Comment: Yes you can do it by defining different brokers (redis) in different nodes, But I would suggest having only one redis for your whole app, if Redis is getting overloaded try to upgrade your redis instead of getting new redis.

Comment: How about Redis cluster? You will have single endpoint but multiple instances(nodes) of Redis to handle the load.